# How do I login with my old account (not OpenID)?

Tags: support, openid

Months ago I created a login with my email and password. But now it insists on an OpenID login, and I see no way around this. Even the info on how to link an old account with an OpenID account is wrong.

Help!

Comment: Account authentication has always only used OpenID.

Comment: should be moved to meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: **`[status-WTF?]`**

Answer (score 3):

The logins for Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault have always been OpenID.

It is possible that you registered with an email address at one of the OpenID providers linked to at the login page.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to figure out which OpenId account you used before (e.g. Facebook, Gmail), try recovering your account here:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery